# Cent OS 6.8 smbv2

Tags: centos, samba, server-message-block

I'm running a linux system with CentOS 6.8 and I need to connect to a network share that only supports smbv2.
Unfortunately, that doesn't work because currently only smbv1 is used.

Is there any possibility to get smbv2 running? Maybe an upgrade of the samba version?

Or do I need a complete new Cent OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either upgrade to CentOS 7.x which has Samba 4.x packages as the default, or on CentOS 6.x there are some additional `samba4*` packages that you can install instead of the default Samba 3.x packages. You will need to use one set of packages or the other, both versions won't coexist.

Answer (score 1):

For servers configuration, Put a line `min protocol = SMB2` in `[global]` section of smb.conf.

Ref: How to force SMB2 protocol in samba?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/546743/how-to-force-smb2-protocol-in-samba

Both Ubuntu and CentOS uses Samba.

smbclient(1) can only specify available max protocol version with `-m|-max-protocol SMB2`. Another client(mount.cifs) may refer smb.conf.

Notes: added smbclient(1) -m|-max-protocol option description to tell protocol version for servers.

Comment: mmh no! that's only for the server. When you run a samba server. I need it as a client.